# Spring Boot (v2.3.1) integration with swagger (v2.9.2) fails only for swagger-ui but works fine with swagger (v 2.8.0)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I am trying to integrate swagger v2.9.2 or any latest version with spring boot v2.3.1 but it is not loading swagger-ui.html end-point (says 404 error) whereas /v2/api-docs works perfectly. Below mentioned are the configurations :

```
 @Configuration
    
    @EnableSwagger2
    
    public class ResourceHandlerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{
    
         @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry
                        .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    
                registry
                        .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
            }
    
            @Bean
            public Docket apiDocket() {
    
                return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                        .apiInfo(getApiInfo())
                        .select()
                        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com"))
                        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                        .build();
            }
    
            private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {
    
                return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                        .title("Swagger API Doc")
                        .description("More description about the API")
                        .version("1.0.0")
                        .build();
            }
    }
```

and following dependencies in pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/webjars-locator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.40</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please help me with the proper configuration for latest version integration.

Comment: do you use hateoas dependencies too ?

Comment: No, I am not using hateoas dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WebMvcConfigurerAdapter instead of WebMvcConfigurationSupport, when you implement WebMvcConfigurationSupport, spring boot assumes you're in charge of all the configuration and will disable auto configuration.

Comment: Unable to find WebMvcConfigurerAdapter or probably it is deprecated so used WebMvcConfigurer instead but didn't work that as well. @EnableSwagger2 is also removed in the latest version dependencies.